# Looking for location of tmp directory in flatpak

Tags: octave, flatpak

Looking for location of tmp directory in flatpak.
I installed the Octave flatpak.  When I go to access the tmp directory while in the Octave program the directory is not the same tmp directory if accessed using a file manager to access /tmp/   where is the Octave flatpak tmp directory located?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The full path follows the pattern:

```
/run/user/USERID/.flatpak/FLATPAK_ID/tmp/
```

Where USERID is your user id (obtainable through `id` command, usually 1000 or more), and FLATPAK_ID is flatpak image URI (looks like reversed DNS name, e.g. org.octave.Octave).

So, assuming your user id is 1000, then Octave flatpak tmp directory would be

```
/run/user/1000/.flatpak/org.octave.Octave/tmp/
```